# Problemas al instalar Jenkins en Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, linux, bash, ubuntu, jenkins

Estoy tratando de instalar Jenkins en una MV con Ubuntu 20.04 ejecutando los siguientes códigos:

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install jenkins -y
```

Pero cuando ejecuto todo este código, en el momento de instalar Jenkins, recibo lo siguiente:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jenkins
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 91.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 95.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.332.3
  Redirection from https to 'http://mirrors.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb' is forbidden [IP: 146.75.30.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb  Redirection from https to 'http://mirrors.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb' is forbidden [IP: 146.75.30.133 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

¿Hay alguna manera de poder arreglar este problema?

Comment: https://github.com/jenkins-infra/helpdesk/issues/2957